# File IO and strings unexpected values in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, file-io, buffer

I have written this program in C to print a part of long case statement of another program. But it is printing unexpected values and I am not able to debug it. Please help.

PROGRAM:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i=0, N=32, att=0, attbuf=0;
    float fout=6000.0;
    unsigned long ftw;
    long double fin;
    char *ddata;
    char *dbit="32'b";
    char *pdata;
    char *adata;
    char *abit="5'b";
    char *buffer1;
    char *buffer2;
    fp = fopen("test1.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        puts("Cannot open target file");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
    {
        fin = fout / N;
        if((fin== (long double)(3500/11)) || (fin==(3500/10)) || (fin==(long double)(3500/9)) || (fin==(double)(3500/8)) || (fin==(3500/7)))
    {
            N = 36;
            fin = fout / N;
        }
    ftw = (long)((pow(2,32)*(fin/3500))+0.5);
    itoa(ftw, buffer1, 2);
    ddata = strcat(dbit, buffer1);

    if(N == 32)
    {
        pdata = "8'b10000000";
    }
    else if (N == 36)
    {
        pdata = "8'b10000010";
    }
    puts(pdata);

    if((fout >= 6000) && (fout <= 10000))
    {
        att = 0;
    }
    attbuf = ~att;
    itoa(attbuf, buffer2, 2);
    adata = strcat(abit, buffer2);

    fputs("\t\t\t\t\t", fp);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\t:\tbegin\n",i);
    fprintf(fp, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\to_data [31:0] <= %s;\n", ddata);
    fprintf(fp, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\to_pdata [7:0] <= %s;\n", pdata);
    fprintf(fp, "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\to_adata [4:0] <= %s;\n", adata);
}
    fclose(fp);

}
```

The output I am getting is this :

```
0   :   begin
o_data [31:0] <= 32'b11011011011011101111111111111111;
o_pdata [7:0] <= 8'b10000000;
o_adata [4:0] <= 1011011011011101111111111111111;
1   :   begin
o_data [31:0] <= 32'b1101101101101110111111111111111111011011011011101111111111111111;
o_pdata [7:0] <= 8'b10000000;
o_adata [4:0] <= 101101101101110111111111111111111011011011011101111111111111111;
```

The output I want is as follows :

```
0   :   begin
o_data [31:0] <= 32'b11011011011011101111111111111111;
o_pdata [7:0] <= 8'b10000000;
o_adata [4:0] <= 5'b11111;
1   :   begin
o_data [31:0] <= 32'b11011011011011101111111111111111;
o_pdata [7:0] <= 8'b10000000;
o_adata [4:0] <= 5'b11111;
```

why is this happening?

Comment: I see a slurry of pointers, and not a single allocation or valid assignment of address. Add to that writing to read-only string literals and you're invoke of *undefined behavior* runs deep.

Comment: Thank you. Can you kindly point out some of the invalid lines. Why a garbage value is coming for adata and why ddata is sort of getting appended next time? If i comment the code from first statement of for loop upto the assignement of ddata the adata is coming fine but I need to truncate it upto 5-bit binary, which I am not able to do.

Comment: `ddata = strcat(dbit, buffer1);`, `adata = strcat(abit, buffer2);` : Cannot be concatenated such Because 1) `dbit` and `abit` is a string literal. 2) There is not enough space to store the result of the consolidation.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for explaining the faulty assignments. Your suggestion worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Code like this:

```
fin == (long double)(3500/11)
```

doesn't mean what you probably expect it to mean. The division happens *as integer*, since both `3500` and `11` are integers. The cast just converts the final resulting integer to `long double`, it doesn't make the division be floating-point.

For that, you need e.g. `fin = (long double) 3500 / 11`.

Also, that said, it's as usual a very bad idea to compare floating-point numbers for exact equality with `==`. It's *much better* to threshold the distance from the desired value.

Comment: I have declared fin as a long double. In that statement I want to check whether the fin value which is calculated as fout/N is equal to 3500/11. How to preserve the result as a floating point value with many significant digits after decimal?

Comment: @user3776279 My point is that the type of `fin` doesn't matter, like I said above. Neither does the cast, since it (due to the parentheses) "misses" the expression it's meant to affect.